# How to take a derivative of terms inside an integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm having trouble understanding a result from the Black (1995) search model. Workers search (with cost $\kappa$) for a job, and there is a fraction $(1-\theta)$ of amenable employers. All are paid wage $w$, have reservation utility $u_r$ (below which they do not accept a job), and have idiosyncratic value of working $\alpha$.

Suppose $\kappa$, $\theta$, $w$ are constants, $\alpha$ is a random variable with probability density function $f(\alpha)$ and c.d.f. $F(\alpha)$ (it is also given that the Mills ratio $[1-F(\alpha)]/f(\alpha)$ is decreasing), and $\alpha_0\equiv u_r-w$.

How does it follow that

$$
du_r/d\theta < 0
$$

from the following equation, which is used to pin down $u_r$?
$$
\kappa /(1-\theta)=\int_{\alpha_0}^{\infty}\left(w+\alpha-u_{\mathrm{r}}\right) f(\alpha) d \alpha
$$

Comment: please provide explanation of what all those terms are so we can understand better :)

Comment: But at first glance I'd say that you can differentiate both sides with respect to $\theta$ to try and find that relation

Comment: How does that look?

Comment: In the right-hand side you can interchange the derivative with the integral, so you basically take the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$ of the integrand. Also, is $F(\alpha)$ related to $f$ in any way?

Comment: F is the cdf -- added this to the question